# Magento 2.1 Ccsave

Tags: magento2

I was disappointed to find out Magento 2 does not have a Ccsave option. The only credit card option is with Braintree but they are making me jump through hoops with their application process. Is there a simple way I can add ccsave from Magento 1 to Magento 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom payment method to re-implement the Saved CC method from M1. There is a sample payment module here that could be used as a starting point: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway

That being said, leaving it out was a very intentional decision. Storing credit card details on-site in your database is terrible for security and PCI compliance, regardless of what security measures you might put in place. The fact is, if your store in any way got compromised, every bit of that data on file is at risk.

There are numerous credit card gateways supported out-of-box by Magento 2 (PayPal, Braintree, Authorize.Net), and many more that can be added with third-party modules. Find a credit card processor you can work with, and do it right.

Comment: @Royan Hoerr yes correct m2 doesn't have. but there is a scenario m1 site used saved card cc payment method when they are going to migrate to m2 how they going to handle for open orders at the of migration. Your valuable suggestion is required. Please advise